# ¿Como evitar que se cree una nueva columna vacía?

Tags: html5, angularjs-2.0, loops, angular-directivas, angular-material

Estoy realizando una aplicación que maneja productos y, los tipos de estos. Estoy mostrandolos dependiendo el stock del producto:

```
<mat-tab-group class="demo-tab-group">
<mat-tab label="{{ type.name }}" *ngFor="let type of productService.productTypes">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div *ngFor="let product of productService.products" class="col-2 mb-r">
                <br>
                <div class="card border-danger" *ngIf="(product.Type == type.name)" >
                    <mat-card class="example-card">
                        <img  mat-card-image src="http://localhost/img/{{ product.image }}" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
                        <h4 >{{ product.name }}</h4>
                        <mat-card-content>
                            {{ product.Type }}
                            <mat-chip-list>
                                <mat-chip color="accent" selected="true">product outta stock</mat-chip>
                            </mat-chip-list>
                            Price: Q {{ product.price }}
                            <div class="card border-danger" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
                                <button mat-button (click)="goToDetails(product.idProduct)">detail</button>
                            </div>
                        </mat-card-content>
                    </mat-card>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</mat-tab>
```

El primer `for` recorre todos los tipos, el segundo cada producto y, finalmente si el tipo de producto concuerda con el nombre del tipo, se imprime una `card` del material design de angular.

El problema con el que me encontré fué este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me crea una columna vacía, donde no hay nada, y donde deberían ir las demas `cards` que se generan.

¿Tienes alguna idea de como puedo evitar que se creen estas columnas vacías y, que todas las `cards` esten ordenadas de manera correcta?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que tienes un `*ngFor` que va a crear sí o sí un div, y luego tienes un `*ngIf` que decide si se rellena o no. Una solución simple es la siguiente: transforma tu código actual

```
<div *ngFor="let product of productService.products" class="col-2 mb-r">
  <br>
  <div class="card border-danger" *ngIf="(product.Type == type.name)" >
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

a esto:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let product of productService.products">
  <div *ngIf="(product.Type == type.name)" class="col-2 mb-r">
    <br>
    <div class="card border-danger"  >
     ...
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

el tag `ng-container` no muestra nada, es un "truco" de angular para poder iterar sin tener que envolver cualquier código en un elemento HTML